# php foreach loop counts multiple iterations of the same ID as one

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, woocommerce

I have a loop for woocommerce to print the category name of each item in my shopping cart. This is the code:

```
function myFunction(){
global $woocommerce;

foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $_product = $values['data'];
    $terms = get_the_terms( $_product->id, 'product_cat' );

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $_categoryid = $term->name;
        echo $term->name;

    }   
}
}
```

it works and `echo $term->name;` will echo the array, however, if I have let's say a quantity of two of the same item, aka 2 identical `$_product->id`'s it will only list it as 1 item in the echo. I need it to list every single item seperatly.

### Example

I have three items in the cart

item 1) `$_product->id` is 20 (category is hat)

item 2) `$_product->id` is 20 (category is hat)

item 3) `$_product->id` is 15 (category is shirt)

the echo will show: hat shirt

I need it to show: hat hat shirt

Comment: items 1 and 2 are identical so they would be a single entry with a quantity of 2

Answer (score 0):

If you need items separately then use the counter as:

1. First find the total count of items.
2. Then put a counter for each item printed.
   Here is the code.

   ```
   function myFunction(){
      global $woocommerce;

      foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
   $_product = $values['data'];
   $terms = get_the_terms( $_product->id, 'product_cat' );
   $count = count($terms);
   $i = 0;
   foreach ($terms as $term) {
     $i++;
       $_categoryid = $term->name;
        if($i < $count){
          echo $term->name;
        }

   }   
    }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)

it gives this error, though

`Catchable fatal error: Object of class WC_Product_Simple could not be converted to string in /home/chaugen/public_html/wp-content/themes/DiscoverYourWonder/functions.php on line 203`

which is the `$i++;` line

Comment: sorry by mistake i wrote ($i < $term) it is ($i < $count), I have edited it above. And make sure that $term->name is not an object at the end! (what you can check via var_dump($term->name); in the line after the assignment)

Comment: Hmmm well it's good that we caught the error :) however, $count is equal to 1 even if the quantity is 100, so the if statement stops after 1 echo of the name.